# Modal box overflowing

Tags: html, css, scroll, modal-dialog

i got modal box with list content. but the list got longer than expected. im not suppose to extend the modal box longer. how can i make it scrollable. or split the modal so it shows it in another box. the list is updated automatically from xml

```
<div id="div1" 
style="width:600px;height:480px; display:none;background-color:#7cd350; border-radius: 10px; z-index: -999; position:absolute; z-index:1;" >
<button style="background:none; border:none; float:right;" id="button3">
<img src="images/btn_close_diction0001.png"/>
</button> 
<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("dataMain.xml");
document.write("<div style='padding-top:50px;padding-left:20px;font-color:#111;'>");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('menu');
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write("<li class='duudah'>");
document.write("<a href='huudas");
document.write(i);
document.write(".html' style='padding:30 25px;'>");
document.write(x[i].getAttribute('id'));
document.write(":");
document.write("    ");
document.write(x[i].getAttribute('name'));
document.write("</a>");
document.write("</li>");
document.write("<br>");
} 
document.write("</div>");
</script>
        </div>




   .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand you right, but just change

```
overflow: auto;
```

instead of hidden in your .modal class. additionally you may want to add width and height to the div.

Comment: i do have height and width on div. height of 480px (not allowed to make it longer) but the list inside is gone longer. i just wanna fit the list in 480px modal window. either by scrolling or another modal next to it.